# Brace highlighting in Nano text editor?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, nano

Is there a method for highlighting matched brace pairs in nano text editor?
My understanding is syntax can be changed in the config file, but unlike gedit there is no gui option to select brace highlighting.

Alternately, im more than happy to hear sugfestio s for a text editor thats linux compatible and semi-light weight.

*Needs to be compatible with c++.

Comment: That is simply not an option.

Comment: Would this be more appropriate question in unix.stackexchange.com as it is about configuration of a program, rather than programming?

Comment: Ok, ill need to look for a new text editor that doest have that possibility, just not gedit. Any suggedtions?